# How do JavaScript engines convert async/await to promises under the hood?

Tags: javascript, async, promises, language-discussion

I'm curious how the async/await syntax is converted to `Promise`s.  Maybe I'm just not thinking about it properly, but I don't know how this code would be converted to a Promise:

```js
async function myFunc(doAwait) {
    doSomething();
    if (doAwait) {
        await doSomethingAsync();
    }

    return doSomethingElse();
}
```

When `doAwait` is `false`, I'd expect this function to run equivalent to:

```js
return new Promise(res => {
    doSomething();
    res(doSomethingElse());
});
```

If it's `true`, it would be:

```js
return new Promise(() => { doSomething(); })
    .then(() => doSomethingAsync())
    .then(() => doSomethingElse());
```

It could do something like:

```js
let p = new Promise(() => { doSomething(); });
if (doAwait) {
    p = p.then(() => doSomethingAsync());
}
return p.then(() => doSomethingElse());
```

But that introduces an extra, possibly unnecessary `then`.  Maybe that's just unavoidable.

Answer (score 5):

This `async/await` code:

```
async function myFunc(doAwait) {
    doSomething();
    if (doAwait) {
        await doSomethingAsync();
    }

    return doSomethingElse();
}
```

Would be basically equivalent to this:

```
function myFunc(doAwait) {
    doSomething();
    if (doAwait) {
        return Promise.resolve(doSomethingAsync()).then(doSomethingElse);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(doSomethingElse());
}
```

For complete equivalence, including synchronous exceptions in any of the functions calls, it would be something like this:

```
function myFunc(doAwait) {
    try {
        doSomething();
        if (doAwait) {
            return Promise.resolve(doSomethingAsync()).then(doSomethingElse);
        }

        return Promise.resolve(doSomethingElse());
    } catch(e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: When `doAwait` is `true`, I don't return the value of `doSomethingAsync`.

Comment: @dx_over_dt - OK, I fixed that.

Comment: So if there were a lot of conditional awaits, it would produce a bunch of stringed, repeated, thens?

Comment: @dx_over_dt - Conditional asynchronous operations are simply a lot easier to code with `async/await`.

Comment: Right, which is why I'm wondering how the engine handles them.

Comment: Well, the engine has `await` functionality built in.  It literally suspends execution of the function body until the promise resolves/rejects.  It doesn't have to rewrite code into `.then()` handlers.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't first transform the code into a `Promise` and then run that.

Comment: It doesn't need to transform it into regular `.then()` code because it can directly suspend function execution.  How exactly a given engine does this is implementation dependent.  It's certainly cleaner if they natively support suspending function execution upon an await without rewriting the logic.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function has to return a promise. So to start with you may consider your;

```
async function af(x){
        ...
        return y;
      }
```

rephrased as

```
function af(x){
  return new Promise(v => ( ...
                          , v(y)
                          )
                    );
}
```

However once you do this you don't really need a `try` and `catch` stage at all since Promises natively handle that.

Please check the following at the dev tools for `af(true,1000)`, `af(true,0)`, `af(false,1000)` and `af(false,0)`;

```
function boom(){
  throw "Boom..!";
}

function doStgSync(b){
  b ? console.log("Did something sycnronous..!")
    : boom();
}

function doAsyncIn(n){
  return new Promise((v,x) => n ? setTimeout( v
                                            , n
                                            , `Async operation done in ${n}ms`
                                            )
                                : x("ZERO ZERO BANG BANG..!")
                    );
}

function af(b,n){
  return new Promise(v => ( doStgSync(b)
                          , v(doAsyncIn(n))
                          )
                    );
}

af(true,1000).then(console.log)
             .catch(e => console.log(`Got error: ${e}`));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Can you convert my example async function into a `Promise` chain?

Comment: @dx_over_dt It is basically the same code. The synchronous `doSomething` function in your code is `doStgSync(b)` function in my code. If it's argument `b` is `true` it just works or throws an error if it is `false`. Your `doSomethingAsync` function is `doAsyncIn(n)` in my code. If `n` argument is `0` then it rejects or if not takes that many ms to resolve.